# DestroyIcon not Destroying?

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I'm using the SHGetFileInfo API to return the icon associated with some extensions like this:

```
 If SHGetFileInfo("n.exe", FileAttributeNormal, _shFIleInfo, Marshal.SizeOf(_shFIleInfo), ShgfiUseFileAttributes Or ShgfiIcon Or ShgfiSmallIcon) <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Success")
    End If
```

Where _shFileInfo is the structure:

```
  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Public Structure ShFileInfo
    Public hIcon As IntPtr
    Public iIcon As Integer
    Public dwAttributes As UInteger
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> _
    Public szDisplayName As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=80)> _
    Public szTypeName As String
End Structure
```

using these flags:

```
Private Const ShgfiUseFileAttributes As UInteger = &H10
Private Const ShgfiSmallIcon As UInteger = &H1
Private Const ShgfiIcon As UInteger = &H100
```

I can get the icon handle from _shFIleInfo.hIcon which is what i want

What i noticed is after i've disposed it, i still can access the Handle as it doesn't throw error in the line below.

```
 Public Sub DisposeShFileInfo()
    If DestroyIcon(_shFIleInfo.hIcon) Then
        Debug.WriteLine("Disposed")
        Debug.Writeline(_shFIleInfo.hIcon)
    End If
End Sub
```

Is this normal behaviour or am i missing something?

Comment: Shell icons are also a system resource which may mean that any attempt to destroy them will silently fail. ps. I upvoted the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `HICON` is nothing more than an opaque handle. In C# this is represented with `IntPtr`. You can call `DestroyIcon` to finalize the object behind the handle. When you print the value of the handle you still get a value. But if you try to pass this now destroyed handle value to another API function, that function call will fail.

In C terms this is analogous to the following:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
free(p);
// p is not null, but is now a stale pointer
```

Comment: That makes sense, i was thinking something like that, thanks.